# Is it possible to upsert documents in elasticsearch based on a given field other than _id?

Tags: elasticsearch, upsert

I have an index with documents as follows

```
{ "StartId": "123a", "EndId": "123b", "Tag": "tag1" }
{ "StartId": "234a", "EndId": "234b", "Tag": "tag2" }
{ "StartId": "345a", "EndId": "345b", "Tag": "tag3" }
{ "StartId": "456a", "EndId": "456b", "Tag": "tag4" }
```

Now I have a new document
`{ "StartId": "567a", "EndId": "567b", "Tag": "tag5" }`

If `StartId` from new doc already exists in the index, I want to update it with the data in new doc else I want to insert the new document.

I know how to upsert by `_id`

```
POST test/_update/1
{
  "doc": {
    "name": "new_name"
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

But is it possible to upsert by any field other than `_id`? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**No, it's not possible in one go.**

`doc_as_upsert` is reserved for the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert) which requires an `_id` in the request's URI path.

---

You *can*, however, update documents without knowing the `_id` through the [Update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query):

```json
POST test-index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
      if (ctx._source['StartId'] == params['StartId']) {
        ctx._source.putAll(params['upsertWith']);
      }
    """,
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "StartId": "567a",
      "upsertWith": {
        "name": "new_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but **upserting** is impossible because [`ctx['_id']` is read-only](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-update-by-query-context.html#painless-update-by-query-context). You can, however, [**delete**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source) documents with it.